# Scraping .aspx page in node

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, scraper, cheerio

I've been working on scraping the following site: http://www.fightingillini.com/schedule.aspx?path=softball

I've had extensive experience using node/cheerio/scraperjs to scrape both static and dynamic content in the past, but I'm not having any luck cracking this site.

```
        scraperjs.DynamicScraper.create('http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.ashx/calendar.rss?sport_id=9')
            .scrape(function() {
              return $('item').map(function() {
                return $(this).children('title').text();
              }).get();
            }, function(list) {
              console.log(list);
            });
```

Any help/feedback/suggestions on libraries to use would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net web forms pages can be notoriously difficult to scrape, because of the complicated ViewState hidden form input. Some times that's even a feature ;)

In this case, I would go for the rss feed, found via one of the links on the page you are trying to scrape:

> http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.ashx/calendar.rss?sport_id=9

The link will give you the same content, but in a much-friendlier and standard XML format. The code to parse this will likely be easier to parse correctly. Most of all, the format here is guaranteed to be *stable*, whereas on the regular page even small tweaks to the site theme could throw your parsing code off.

The point is that rss links are, in a sense, *made for scraping*, so look there first.

Here's an example of one of the current entries:

```
<item>
<title>2/6 11:30 AM [L] Softball vs  Winthrop</title>
<description>L 1-5 http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.aspx?id=8670</description>
<link>http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.aspx?id=8670</link>
<guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.aspx?id=8670</guid>
<ev:gameid>8670</ev:gameid>
<ev:location>Athens, Ga.</ev:location>
<ev:startdate>2015-02-06T17:30:00.0000000Z</ev:startdate>
<ev:enddate>2015-02-06T20:30:00.0000000Z</ev:enddate>
<s:localstartdate>2015-02-06T11:30:00.0000000</s:localstartdate>
<s:localenddate>2015-02-06T14:30:00.0000000</s:localenddate>
<s:teamlogo>http://www.fightingillini.com/images/logos/site/site.png</s:teamlogo>
<s:opponentlogo>http://www.fightingillini.com/images/logos/z16.png</s:opponentlogo>
<s:links>
</s:links>
</item>
```

The page also has an [iCal link](http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.ashx/calendar.ics?sport_id=9&_=b5369c9c-e889-4089-8e4c-253bd065383e), if that works better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually tried looking into the rss feed, but that seemed to have the same problem as the other page, it returned an empty body. It seems like it may be a lost cause.

Comment: Try enclosing the url in the code in single quotes: `scraperjs.DynamicScraper.create('http://www.fightingillini.com/....').`

Comment: I've been attempting to scrape the rss feeds with the regular request module...

`request('http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.ashx/calendar.rss?sport_id=9', cb1);`

and I'm still turning up an empty body... thanks for all the help

Comment: Found the solution, needed to add a 'User-Agent' header in order to scrape the page. For anyone interested, here was my final request:
                `request({
                  url: 'http://www.fightingillini.com/calendar.ashx/calendar.rss?sport_id=9',
                  headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)'
                  }
                }, cb1);`